# Tcp data is getting attached in each other

Tags: tcp, stream, server, client

I have a problem using tcp.
When i read and write data in the client or the server he should read it as one packet each time.

But sometimes when i write data very fast (in a loop for a example) the client received it as a one data instead of handle it as three different packets for example.

Sending data:

```
messageToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);        
c.GetStream().Write(messageToSend, 0, messageToSend.Length);
```

Receiving in the client:

```
byte[] message = new byte[1024];
int i = 0;
i = c.GetStream().Read(message, 0, message.Length);
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, i);
//Handle the new data....
```

Hope it was clear enough and thanks in advance!

Comment: Show how you're writing data to the client.

Comment: something like that:                                                                                     `messageToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                                                                            c.GetStream().Write(messageToSend, 0, messageToSend.Length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP by design is stream protocol it gets stacked up in the buffer if you are not fast enough to read it out. UDP for instance is dgram protocol that has fixed packets that are readable separately.

Comment: Yes i did use UDP before this one, but i wanted to try TCP. is there a flag or someting that can help me?

Comment: @cnc No. TCP doesn't provide you with a packet/frame API. You'll need to handle that yourself in some manner in the data you send/receive on top of TCP  so you can separate packets that's meaningful to your application  from each other, and so you can know when you have a complete packet, etc.

Comment: @nos So you are saying that i need to add to the string BEGIN and END and split it?

Comment: @cnc Yes, that's one way, note that you might not get everything between those "BEGIN" and "END" with one .Read() call, or you might get several. Or anything inbetween, so you'll need to handle that too. Or you could prefix each packet you want to send with the length of the packet, and first read that length to know how much data you need to read.

Comment: @cnc This isn't even true for UDP. A single UDP datagram can be split over multiple packets.